# How to fetch the execution time of all methods in a class using LambdaMetaFactory?

Tags: java, performance, reflection, lambda-metafactory

`I'm trying to fetch the execution time of a getName() method of Person's class by using LambdaMetaFactory instead of using AOP to improve the performance.

But Facing below exception when tried with the code mentioned:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractethodError : Receiver Class does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void invoke ()'   of interface GetterFunction.`

**MyCode:**

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        GetterFunction getterFunction;
        final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class, Person.class);
        final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
                "invoke",
                MethodType.methodType(GetterFunction.class),
                methodType,
                lookup.findVirtual(Person.class, "getName", MethodType.methodType(String.class)),
                methodType);
        getterFunction = (GetterFunction) site.getTarget().invokeExact();
       getterFunction.invoke());
    }

    void invoke(GetterFunction getterFunction){
      long startTime = System.CurrentMilliSeconds();
       for(int i= 0 ; i<3 ; i++){
         getterFunction.invoke();
       }
       long endTime = System.CurrentMilliSeconds();
       System.out.println("Executed Time of a method :: "+ (endTime - startTime));
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface GetterFunction {

        void invoke();
    }

    static class Person {

        String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

}`
```

Comment: [This seems awfully familiar...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78167056/5133585)

Comment: @Slaw .. I'm new to Reflections .. Can u please add the code with changes .. so that it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your question's title, your issue is not related to benchmarking execution time, but rather how to implement a functional interface dynamically via `LambdaMetafactory`. I strongly recommend reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) to properly understand the API.

Everything below discusses the issues you are having with `LambdaMetafactory`. There is nothing about writing benchmarking code. I recommend reading [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/5133585) for such information. In short, you should use a framework like the *Java Microbenchmark Harness* (JMH).

---

## The Exception

The `AbstractMethodError` you are seeing is due to passing an incorrect `MethodType` argument for the `interfaceMethodType` parameter. You are passing:

```java
MethodType.methodType(String.class, Person.class)
```

But that does not match your `GetterFunction::invoke()` method whose return type is `void`, not `String`, and which as zero parameters, not a single parameter of type `Person`. Thus, you have not actually implemented the `invoke` method. Technically, you should be passing:

```java
MethodType.methodType(void.class)
```

However, while that will solve the immediate error, it will not give you what you want. The code has other issues.

---

## Functional Interface API

Your `GetterFunction` interface is clearly meant to be a "getter proxy". When you call `invoke` it is supposed to return the value of some object's property. Unfortunately, you defined the return type to be `void`, which means it cannot return anything. You need to fix the return type. Presumably you want this interface to be able to work with any property type, so you should make the interface generic and have `invoke` return `T`.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GetterFunction<T> {

  T invoke();
}
```

### Capturing vs Argument

You should also consider whether you want to *capture* an instance of the object you want to call a getter on, or if you want to give `invoke` a parameter so that you can pass any object of a given type.

#### Capturing

If you were to implement the above `GetterFunction` as a lambda it would look like:

```java
Person person = new Person("John Doe");
GetterFunction<String> getter = () -> person.getName();
```

That lambda has *captured* the `person` instance. Each call to `getter.invoke()` will return the name of that specific person. An upside to this approach is that you do not need to keep an explicit reference to the person in order to call the getter. But a downside is that you can never change which person you invoke the getter on.

You have to represent this capturing when creating a `GetterFunction` via `LambdaMetafactory` as well. This is done via the `factoryType` argument. In this case, the argument would be:

```java
MethodType.methodType(GetterFunction.class, Person.class)
```

And then you would need to pass a `Person` when creating the `GetterFunction`:

```java
site.getTarget().invokeExact(somePersonObject)
```

#### Argument

The other option to capturing the object is to give `invoke` a parameter.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GetterFunction<T, U> {

  U invoke(T instance);
}
```

An upside to this is that you can create a single `GetterFunction` for a given property and then use it with any instance of `T`. A downside is that you now have to have a direct reference to `T` in order to call `invoke`.

Note implementing this `GetterFunction` as a lambda would look like:

```java
GetterFunction<Person, String> getter = person -> person.getName();
```

No more capturing of a `Person`.

---

## Working Example

Here is an example that implements a functional interface via `LambdaMetafactory`. Note this example does not include any benchmark code.

```java
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType;

import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;

public class Main {

  public record Person(String name) {}

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface Getter<T, U> {

    U invoke(T instance);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    // The lookup context.
    var caller = MethodHandles.lookup();

    // The name of the functional interface's method that we are implementing.
    var interfaceMethodName = "invoke";

    // The signature of the CallSite. The return type is 'Getter' because that is the
    // functional interface we are implementing. If you need to implement "capturing"
    // then you would specify parameters for the MethodType as needed.
    var factoryType = methodType(Getter.class);

    // The signature of the functional interface's method that we are implementing. The
    // return type and parameter are both generic in this case. Since the left-most upper
    // bound of each type parameter is 'Object', that is the type used. Note you could also
    // use 'MethodType.genericMethodType(1)' here.
    var interfaceMethodType = methodType(Object.class, Object.class);

    // The method we want the functional interface's method to invoke and return the result
    // of. In other words, the "getter" we want to invoke. Note that in this case 'Person' is
    // a record, so the accessor method's name is just "name", not "getName".
    var implementation = caller.findVirtual(Person.class, "name", methodType(String.class));

    // The "parameterization" of the *generic* functional interface we are implementing. This
    // example is specifically creating a `Getter<Person, String>` to get the name of a given
    // 'Person' object.
    var dynamicMethodType = methodType(String.class, Person.class);

    // Create 'Getter<Person, String>' factory.
    var factory =
        LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            caller,
            interfaceMethodName,
            factoryType,
            interfaceMethodType,
            implementation,
            dynamicMethodType);

    // Create an instance of 'Getter<Person, String>'.
    var getter = (Getter<Person, String>) factory.getTarget().invoke();

    // Test 'getter'.
    var person = new Person("John Doe");
    System.out.println(getter.invoke(person));
  }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
John Doe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for in-depth explanation. Surely will look into benchmarking doc as well

Comment: Note that instead of the two variants of a custom `GetterFunction` interface, one can simply use the already existing `Supplier` or `Function` interfaces. Further, you can simply use the already shown `GetterFunction<Person, String> getter = person -> person.getName();` or even `GetterFunction<Person, String> getter = Person::getName;` without dealing with `LambdaMetafactory` (or just `Function<Person, String> getter = Person::getName;` without a custom interface). The timing of the `getName` method invocation does not depend on whether you use `LambdaMetafactory` manually or implicitly.

Comment: @enthusiast Agreed. Though creating a `GetterFunction` interface for this may help readability. And the questioner wanted to use `LambdaMetafactory`, so my answer assumes they have legitimate reasons for doing so.

Comment: @Slaw.. Can we add timing to this code manually instead of using benchmarking ?

Comment: Have added my code by following the above example . Added the timing explicitly in this code but the results are not as expected. Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong in my code ? I have not used benchmarking here. Just want to test the performance of all approaches.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172567/why-lambdametafactory-is-taking-more-time-to-execute-a-method-in-java