# Why LambdaMetaFactory is taking more time to execute a method in Java?

Tags: java, performance, reflection, lambda-metafactory

I'm trying to do performance testing of the below mentioned code with three scenarios by logging the execution time of a getName method of a Person Class.

1. LambdaMetaFactory
2. Direct Access
3. Reflection

Ideally, reflection should take more time to execute than the LambdaMetaFactory. But, my output is surprising as shown below :

```
Lambda Exec Time :: 3510309 ns
Direct Exec Time :: 2701586 ns
Reflection Exec Time :: 10 ns
```

Are there any issues in the code?

My code:

```
package com.jpmc.util.test.reflection;

import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PerformanceTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {

        //LambdaMetaFactory
        var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        var interfaceMethodName = "invoke";
        var factoryType = MethodType.methodType(GetterFunction.class);
        var interfaceMethodType = MethodType.methodType(Object.class,Object.class);
        var implementation = lookup.findVirtual(Person.class,"getName",MethodType.methodType(String.class));
        var dynamicMethodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class,Person.class);

        var factory = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
                interfaceMethodName,
                factoryType,
                interfaceMethodType,
                implementation,
                dynamicMethodType);

        var getterFunction = (GetterFunction<Person,String>) factory.getTarget().invoke();
        Person  person = new Person("Joe");
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int runs = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            getterFunction.invoke(person);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println( "Lambda Exec Time :: "+ (endTime-startTime) + " ns");

       //Direct Access
     
        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
                //direct access
                person.getName();
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.println( "Direct Exec Time :: "+ time + " ns");
        }

        //Reflection
        Method getNameMethod = Person.class.getMethod("getName");
        {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
                //reflection access
                getNameMethod.invoke(person);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.println( "Reflection Exec Time :: "+ time+ " ns");
        }
    }

}


@FunctionalInterface
interface GetterFunction<T,U> {
    U  invoke (T instance);
}

 class Person {
        String name;
        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return name;
     }
 }
```

### Edited

Have understood to use benchmarking. But, is it mandatory to use benchmarking for LambdaMetaFactory to log the execution time ? Just want to get the execution time of all approaches (LambdaMetaFactory, Reflection, DirectAccess) via simple Java code.

What are the results unexpected and what changes do I need to make for desired results?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/5133585) first. You should use JMH to measure the execution time. Your results are likely incorrect.

Comment: @Sweeper, I have edited the code . Can you please let me know where exactly the problem lies in the code ? so that it will be helpful

Comment: My guess is that JIT optimized something in the reflection test. This is why JMH is recommended so much for this sort of thing. Note from my own benchmarks on Java 21, I got `0.998 ± 0.024 ns/op` for "direct", `0.993 ± 0.017 ns/op` for "metafactory", and `8.593 ± 0.146 ns/op` for "reflection". From that we can see there's no difference between "direct" and "metafactory", and "reflection" is slower but not by much (at least in absolute terms; though I suppose the 8 ns could add up if you call it many, many times in a tight loop).

Comment: @Slaw it’s much simpler; the reason for those surprising results is that the OP out of a sudden uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `System.nanoTime()` for the Reflection test. Of course, that results in numbers off by a factor of one million…

Comment: @Holger That would make more sense. Nice catch.

Comment: @dev333 Holger spotted the reason why your measured time for "reflection" is so drastically different. But just want to mention that does not negate the advice to use JMH for this sort of thing.

Comment: Tip for all your questions here: ask how **you** can fix it, not how others can fix it for you. The latter sounds lazy (even if you are not) and conversely readers are happy to see expressions of self-reliance. Of course, readers are here to help question authors, not to do all their work. (I have not voted, but I see you received -2 for this question).